# Spreadsheet chart function no permission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#charts).

Under charts there is some sample code to generate a chart in GAS:

```
function newChart() {
      // Generate a chart representing the data in the range of A1:B15.
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

      var chart = sheet.newChart()
         .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
         .addRange(sheet.getRange('A1:B15'))
         .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
         .build();

      sheet.insertChart(chart);
    }
```

I added dummy data in the range A1:B15 for the active sheet. Then, in cell D2 I typed `=newChart()`

The an error is returned "You do not have permission to call insertChart (line 12)." I Googled that error and found [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) documentation. In it there is a sentence "If your custom function throws the error message You do not have permission to call X service., the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function."

The example is from the documentation too.

1. Why would the documentation provide me an example that is not appropriate in a custom function?
2. How do I get the function to "work" - to return a chart?

[image]

Comment: The names of the custom functions should not be same as the builtin method names. Check this link : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#naming

Comment: newChart is a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the spreadsheet, go to Tools and choose Script Editor. Here click the Run menu and choose newChart from the dropdown. Authorize the script and the formula should work.

Comment: In my case, it's only working using the Run menu in Script Editor while in the spreadsheet the formula still gives the same exception about permission.